# Prolog-Splitting an algebraic expression using only "+" into separate lists of atoms and numbers

Tags: prolog

I am trying to create a predicate split_exp, which takes an algebraic expression that uses only "+" functor and generates two lists, one of the atoms and one of numbers. For example, 1+a+b+3 should generate [1,3] and [a,b]. The expression can be of any length.
I have tried.

```
split_exp(X,[X|[]],[]):-number(X).
split_exp(X,[],[X|[]]):-atom(X).
split_exp(X+Y,[X|Ns],Na):-number(X),split_exp(Y,Ns,Na).
split_exp(X+Y,Ns,[X|Na]):-atom(X),split_exp(Y,Ns,Na).
```

Kindly explain to me where i am going wrong in this implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be easy to spot from your code, corrected and simplified:

```
split_exp(X,[X],[]):-number(X).
split_exp(X,[],[X]):-atom(X).
split_exp(Y+X,[X|Ns],As):-number(X),split_exp(Y,Ns,As).
split_exp(Y+X,Ns,[X|As]):-atom(X),split_exp(Y,Ns,As).
```

Note the recursive call, still using `Y`. Since (+)/2 is left associative (`?- current_op(_,A,+)` yields `A=yfx` as second result, since there is also the unary form), you must recurse on the *left* branch, which I did swapping X and Y subterms in the head(s).

You can show the expression shape using the ISO builtin `?- write_canonical(E)` or `?- display(E).`